# populate combobox inside the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a `DataGrid` to insert data into Sql Server table. Inside of `DataGrid` I have `ComboBox` to pick the data from a codebook (this is the table from the same database) and insert this data into table I bound to `DataGrid`. This is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgrStavke" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="160" Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Artikl ID">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbArticle" Width="120" ></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Article Name" Width="150"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Usluga ID">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbService" Width="120"></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Service Name" Width="150"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

When I choose article id in combobox article, the very next `DataGridTextColumn` should display name of this article. The same is for service. It's possible to insert few articles and services and that's the reason I use `Datagrid`.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MVVM? You should use MVVM to create a ViewModel so that you can have an object that is used as the "selected item" from the `ComboBox` then bind the "selected item" `Article Name` and `Service Name` to the respective datagrid columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the below sample would help you to achieve your goal

In XAML below code used,

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="RecordValues" ObjectType="{x:Type local:RecordTemp}" MethodName="GetPersonList" >            
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  Margin="10,10,73,155" Name="dataGrid1">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Artikl ID" Width="300" 
                                            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedPart, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                            
                                            DisplayMemberPath="ArticleID"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecordValues}}" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Name" Binding="{Binding SelectedPart.ArticleName}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

In C# below code used,

```
public class RecordTemp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    List<PartsList> _value = new List<PartsList>();

   public RecordTemp()
    {
        _value.Add(new PartsList() { ArticleID = "1", ArticleName = "one - 1", ArticleQuantity = 20 });
        _value.Add(new PartsList() { ArticleID = "2", ArticleName = "Two - 2", ArticleQuantity = 10 });
    }

    public List<PartsList> GetPersonList()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    private PartsList _SelectedPart;

    public PartsList SelectedPart
    {
        get { return _SelectedPart; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedPart = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPart");
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null  )
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }     


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



    #endregion
}

 public class PartsList
{
    public string ArticleID { get; set; }
    public double ArticleQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }
    }
```

In the MainWindow the below code could helps to binding the grid.

```
ObservableCollection<RecordTemp> RecordsTemp = new ObservableCollection<RecordTemp>();
RecordsTemp.Add(new RecordTemp());
RecordsTemp.Add(new RecordTemp());
dataGrid1.DataContext = RecordsTemp;
```

Please Comment If you have any clarification needed. I'll help you

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, I need to populate DataGrid filling the columns (combo article Id, combo service Id, ...) and send data to the database. Can I do this using your solution? As I see you fill RecordsTemp line by line, how to retrieve data from database? And do I need DataContext for dataGrid1 because it's important to populate comboboxes (article and service) but not all columns in datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

```
((ComboBox)GRID.Columns[N].FindControl("cmbArticle")).COMBO-BOX-PROPERTY
```

Is this correct syntax? I don't know, I think you are looking for something like that.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is how to databound combobox with db table, I can't see combo in code-behind and don't know how to set its datasource.